# Azure devops custom extension output variables

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I am trying to create an extension using node api which publishes a path variable on completion. 
I did set outputVariables in task.json and tried to use both

```
tl.setVariable('outVar1', 'outVal1'))
tl.setTaskVariable('outVar1', 'outVal1'))
```

task.json (only outvariable section):

```
"OutputVariables": [
        {
            "name": "outVar1",
            "description": "This publish a output variable."
        }
    ],
```

I tried printing it in the subsequent steps in the same job using all the recomended constructs

```
$(taskName.outVar1)
$taskName.outVar1
$outVar1
$(outVar1)
```

But the variable is not visible. I also printed all the environment variables and the variable is not present there.
Is someone able to create an extension which outputs a variable successfully?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare an output variable fro this purpose.

Just set the variable:

```
tl.setVariable("varNamr","varValue", false);
```

The `fasle` indicate that is not a secret variable.

In the enxt steps you can use the variable wirh `$(varName)`.

Comment: API documentation of setVariable says ```@param secret  whether variable is secret.  Multi-line secrets are not allowed.  Optional, defaults to false```